# Sort an associative array with custom order

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array

How can we sort an associative array with custom order? 
My array look like this

```
Array
(
    [pa_color] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_color
            [value] => 
            [position] => 0
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 1
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

    [pa_dimension] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_dimension
            [value] => 
            [position] => 1
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 0
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

    [pa_travel-duration] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_travel-duration
            [value] => 
            [position] => 2
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 0
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

    [pa_travel-type] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_travel-type
            [value] => 
            [position] => 3
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 0
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

    [pa_travelling-with] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_travelling-with
            [value] => 
            [position] => 4
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 0
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

    [pa_volume] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_volume
            [value] => 
            [position] => 5
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 0
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

    [pa_weight] => Array
        (
            [name] => pa_weight
            [value] => 
            [position] => 6
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 0
            [is_taxonomy] => 1
        )

)
```

and i want this array is like `pa_travel-duration` first `pa_volume` second ?? I know there is a native php function `usort` but i could not understand this.

Comment: Order by which key or value ?

Comment: I want to sort by array key like `[pa_dimension]` 1st which is 2nd right now and `[pa_color]` 2nd which is 1st

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work, but im pretty sure there's much better ways to do it:

Code:

```
$array = array("pa_color" => "color",  
              "pa_dimension" => "dimension", 
              "pa_travel-duration" => "Random Stuff: " . rand(100,999),
              "pa_volume" => "volumen"
              );
$tmp = array("pa_travel-duration" =>  $array["pa_travel-duration"],  
            "pa_volume" =>  $array["pa_volume"], 
);

unset($array["pa_travel-duration"], $array["pa_volume"]);
$array = array_merge($tmp,$array);


print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [pa_travel-duration] => Random Stuff: 127
    [pa_volume] => volumen
    [pa_color] => color
    [pa_dimension] => dimension
)
```

Take care because if the array doesn't have the proper key it will throw an error, you need to add few checks there.

Comment: What if, if array is coming from the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sort_by = array('pa_travel-duration', 'pa_volume', 'pa_color','pa_dimension','pa_travel-type','pa_travelling-with','pa_weight');
$temp_arr = array();
foreach ($sort_by as $key) {
    $temp_arr[$key] = $data[$key];
}
$data = $temp_arr;

echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);
```

Define your order in $sort_by array